# vim: how to set custom lowercased vim commands?

Tags: vim

Vim does not allow you to map commands that are only lowercased. I want to make a command to quickly run my python code and map it to `:rp` command. However I cannot do this:

```
command rp execute "python3 %"
```

as `rp` cannot be only lowercase.

Is there some way I can make this work? Perhaps this is wrong approach altogether and I should use `:make` but I have tried look into documentation of it and I could not figure out how I can use the `make` command to simply run my python script from it.

Thank you for any help on this.

Comment: `:set mp=python3\ %`

Comment: I have tried putting `set mp=python3\ %` into my vimrc and then tried running :mp command with a python file, it didn't work. I am not really sure, perhaps I made some mistake.

Comment: you can add abbreviation for commande mode that change rp to Rp so you have only to type lowercase

Comment: Again, `:help :make`.